# What's a better way to allow users to insert a two-column dataset?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm wanting an efficient way to allow my website's users to upload a list of songs to their profile page. At the moment, I'm using a `<textarea>` in the form that requires specific formatting. The song list must be formatted like this:

```
Some Band Name,Name of the song
Some other Band,Name of that song
...etc
```

My website looks for the comma, and that tells the site that on each line, what comes before the comma is the artist name, and what comes after the comma is the song name. That's a problem though for songs like:

```
Neil Diamond,Girl, You'll be a Woman Soon
```

The second comma in the title of the song screws up the website logic, and what actually gets inserted in their profile is:

```
Neil Diamond, "Girl"
```

What would be a better method for allowing my users to add a list of (sometimes hundreds) of songs to their profile?

Edit: To provide more clarity, I'm looking for a way for a front-end, logged-in user on my website to be able to submit a two-column set of date, through an HTML form. That data would then be submitted through the form into my Wordpress backend, and would each line item would be added as a custom post in Wordpress. I have all the backend logic figured out, but I'm trying to find a better method to allow users to add this data than just using a `<textarea>` input box and hoping that all their data fits the required formatting conditions.

Comment: Are you asking about frontend, backend, database?

Comment: One opinion might be to use the first comma and not all of them...

Comment: @chojnicki It's a frontend textarea form field that I'm currently using, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I edited my original question to provide more clarity.

Comment: @traktor53 Not a bad idea. But what if the artist's name has a comma in it? Like "Earth, Wind, and Fire"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `textarea`, one are artists and other are songs.
You can use another delimiter (`|` instead of `,` is less common is song titles).

You can also do it more "dynamically" with Javascript to add two more inputs when user is clicking a "plus" button. You'll get the POST data as two arrays:

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="https://postman-echo.com/post">
    <div>
        <input name="songs[name][]" value="Girld, You'll be a Woman soon">
        <input name="songs[artist][]" value="Neil Diamond">
    </div>
</form>

<button onclick="addMore()">Add one more song</button>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit form</button>

<script>
/**
 * Add one more song inputs
 */
function addMore() {
    // Create a div
    const div = document.createElement("div");

    // Create the name input
    const name = document.createElement("input");
    name.setAttribute("type", "text");
    name.setAttribute("name", "songs[name][]");
    name.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");

    // Create the artist input
    const artist = document.createElement("input");
    artist.setAttribute("type", "text");
    artist.setAttribute("name", "songs[artist][]");
    artist.setAttribute("placeholder", "Artist");

    // Add the inputs to the div
    div.appendChild(name);
    div.appendChild(artist);

    // Append the div to the form
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(div);
}

/**
 * Submit the form
 */
function submit() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: My concern with separating the data is, what if the site user makes a mistake like they want to add 10 John Denver songs, but have his name in the "Artists' data field listed 11 times? That would throw off all the songs below it.

Having a "Add another line" + sign isn't a bad idea, but sometimes users are wanting to add hundreds of songs. Clicking + hundreds of times isn't ideal, plus they would have to copy/paste each artist and each song name each time, instead of copy/pasting it in from wherever they maintain a song list all at once.

Comment: @brispo you could go for this way and offer an alternative for batch uploads. It's the same approach used in tools like MailChimp to either import a few contacts or a list with hundreds or thousands of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method in PHP with the 3rd parameter `$limit`:

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

So, in your case, if you use `explode(',', 'Neil Diamond,Girl, You'll be a Woman Soon', 2)`, it outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Neil Diamond"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Girl, You'll be a Woman Soon"
}
```

Comment: The problem with only acknowledging the first comma is with songs like, "Earth, Wind, and Fire, September"